# Response code error 400 in jmeter when i am doing performance testing of API

Tags: api, jmeter

[jmeter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5JH4.png) Thread Name:SupplierAPI 1-1
Sample Start:2020-07-30 11:01:04 BST
Load time:571
Connect Time:429
Latency:571
Size in bytes:518
Sent bytes:241
Headers size in bytes:179[image]
Body size in bytes:339
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:400
Response message:Bad Request

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=us-ascii
DataEncoding: us-ascii

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) **`400 Bad Request`** response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
>
> `The client should not repeat this request without modification.`

It means that you're sending syntactically incorrect request so double check the request body, it must be valid [JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) or [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Also don't  forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and configure it to send relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header, in the majority of cases it's `application/json` for REST and `text/xml` or `application/xml` for SOAP. In the latter case you might also need to send SOAPAction header.

In genera it's not very possible to provide the comprehensive answer without seeing your API contract, full configuration of your HTTP Request sampler, Header Manager, request and response details.

Comment: That end point working fine in postman , why its not working in jmeter ?

Comment: I have edit my question , i already done the correct way i dont know why its not responding in jmeter